# os.listdir(path) path not found, while running the program on the Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, windows, keras, jupyter-notebook, operating-system

I am working in a jupyter notebook, on windows 10, trying to run the following program:

```
ad = 'C:\\Users\\S m\\mbdataset\\trainmbds'
CAT = ['0 to 10','10 to 20','20 to 30','30 to 40','40 to 50']
for cat in CAT:
 path = os.path.join(ad, cat)
  for img in os.listdir(path):
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
     plt.imshow(img_array)
      plt.show
      break
    break
```

In the return of the above, I'm getting the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\S m\\mbdataset\\trainmbds\\0 to 10'`

although, the address of the `0 to 10` is `C:\Users\S m\mbdataset\trainmbds\0 to 10` Also, I tried writing the addresses with all kind of slashes (/,\ and \\), it shows the same error.
I'm encountering this problem because I have too many white-spaces in my file path addresses?

Comment: Your syntax looks totally fine to me.  Just for giggles, within notebook, navigate to the folder you are interested, use `%pwd` to get the current directory and check spelling of everything that comes up.

Comment: `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (3) when listing a directory means either that one of the components of the path doesn't exist, e.g. "mbdataset", "trainmbds", or "0 to 10", or the path is too long. If it's exactly what you're showing here, then it's not too long. If `os.listdir(ad)` works, then the problem is "0 to 10".

Comment: Check the listing returned by `os.listdir(ad)`. The directory name that you access has to be exactly the same as in the listing. Copy and paste. Don't assume it's what you think it is. Maybe a "0" is actually an "O" or a "1" is actually an "l" . Maybe there's an extra space, a non-breaking space, or some other invisible character.